cannot read data from API in flutter Web app
I'm working on an app which has a mobile and a web app I have created my custom Nodejs APIs with the MYSQL database, the APIs are working fine in the mobile app. but in I case of flutter web, my post APIs are working fine but I cannot read data from the API, The API is working fine in postman also in the mobile app,    but when I test it in flutter web
I got this error in response. [log] Error fetching products: ClientException: XMLHttpR…, uri=http://127.0.0.1:2000/api/v1/product/getall (using HTTP package)
I also tried the Dio package bit same error [log] Error fetching products: DioException [connection …hich most likely cannot be solved by the library.
here is my function to fetch data :
 Future<List<Product>> fetchProducts() async {
    log("hit");
    final url = Uri.parse(
        '$baseURL:2000/api/v1/product/getall'); // Replace with your local IP and port

    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
        final List<dynamic> data = responseData['data'];
        log('Response data: ${responseData['data']}');

        return data
            .map((productJson) => Product.fromJson(productJson))
            .toList();
      } else {
        log('Failed to load products. Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
        return [];
      }
    } catch (error) {
      log('Error fetching products: $error');
      return [];
    }
  }

NOTE: it works fine in Postman and mobile app, the issue is only in flutter web

I want to read data and show them in my web app

Use your ip address as path instead of 127.0.0.1, this will work fine
